# Why would the Bat-Brand attract violence from other criminals?

Tags: dc, dc-extended-universe, batman-v-superman-dawn-of-justice

In the extended cut of "Batman vs. Superman", Clark Kent can briefly be seen reading an article about Batman branding criminals. The article goes on to explain that criminals branded in such a way were being attacked and/or killed by other criminals inside the prison system.

[image]

I don't understand why the brand would attract this sort of attention, however. If anything, I'd think it would give these prisoners a certain status among their fellow criminals. Unless it's because the other guys fear The Batman *that* much - enough to harm the ones he singles out?

**Why would the Bat-Brand mark attract violence from other criminals, and has such an example of Batman's "victims" being ostracized in the criminal world appeared before in the comics?**

Comment: [Presumably, it's because of Lex' interference](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/56217/11244).

Comment: Additionally, Batman's brand could have been a mark that those crims had spilled the beans. Rats are not treated kindly in prisons.

Comment: The other explanation is that the branded criminals were the "lowest of the low" (rapists, sex traffickers, etc). Those are naturally despised in prisons.

Comment: I am pretty sure it mentions that they were in the movie @Möoz , but heck, I haven't seen that movie in a while... so who knows? (Answer: not me).

Comment: Related question from sister site : [What's with the bat branding and its consequences?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/56194/whats-with-the-bat-branding-and-its-consequences)

Comment: Whatever the explanation, it’s a triumph of Bat-brand-awareness.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

(Quoting [my answer from the Movies SE](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/56217/13595):)

Apparently this is somewhat [explained in the *Ultimate Edition*](http://www.cutprintfilm.com/features/batman-v-superman-ultimate-edition-differences/):

> The theatrical cut made a big deal about Batman branding criminals
>   with a red-hot bat-symbol branding iron, and briefly mentioned that
>   inmates in prisons with this brand are quick to be killed by fellow
>   prisoners… for some reason? It was all kind of vague. **In the *Ultimate
>   Edition* we see that Lex and company pay one of the inmates to “shiv”
>   the latest bat-brandee in the prison yard. This is all part of Lex’s
>   plan to stoke the fires of Superman’s outrage at Batman’s methods.**

[CinemaBlend expands on this](http://www.cinemablend.com/news/1528859/8-major-changes-batman-v-superman-made-for-the-ultimate-edition?story_page=4):

> Remember Cesar Santos? The criminal near the beginning of the movie
>   who Batman branded? Well, there was a lot more to his story in the
>   Ultimate Edition.
>
> We already knew that the Bat-Brand was a death
>   sentence if you're caught with one in prison, but that also makes it a
>   suitable cover for pulling off a sinister assassination. Anatoli is
>   seen paying off one of Cesar's fellow inmates, and later, that same
>   man stabs Cesar to death during recreation time.
>
> Like in the
>   theatrical movie, **Clark is sent pictures of Cesar (by Lex Luthor), but
>   this time, one of the photos is of his corpse.** Clark then goes to
>   Gotham City to learn about Cesar's death, and while the police aren't
>   being cooperative, **he comes across Cesar's girlfriend and son. She
>   tells him that the police know the brand means eventual murder, but
>   they won't do anything about it.** Clark wants to help by telling her
>   story via The Daily Planet, but **she retorts that a pen won't stop
>   Batman, only a fist.**
>
> This helps clear up why Superman was willing to
>   switch from words to force during their later battle.